# How do you do inverse rolling covariance in Python data frame?

Tags: python, dataframe, covariance, inverse, rolling-computation

I am trying to do the inverse rolling covariance estimates on my excess returns, but gets an error in Python. Anyone who knows what is wrong?

This is my excess returns

```
DATES       
1980-01-31  NaN NaN
1980-02-29  -0.029804   -0.160300
1980-03-31  -0.149575   0.075200
1980-04-30  0.013501    0.017034
1980-05-31  0.037237    -0.034638
... ... ...
1999-08-31  0.003183    -0.006510
1999-09-30  -0.064028   -0.003012
1999-10-31  0.055126    -0.016385
1999-11-30  0.027029    -0.012416
1999-12-31  0.024479    -0.021157
```

And I want a rolling covariance matrix that is inverse

```
H = 60
Mu = (excess.rolling(window = H).mean())
Cov = inv(excess.rolling(window = H).cov())

out: LinAlgError: Last 2 dimensions of the array must be square*
```

Comment: What is `excess`? Is it an imported module or an object?

Comment: The excess is just excess return (return - risk free rate) on S&P500 and a 10 year bond index